# Log Garbage Collection in Java Webstart

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jnlp, java-web-start

I want to log the GCs in my Java Webstart Apps.

I already tried the option

```
<j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails" />
```

in the jnlp file, but neither in the java console nor in the specified file gc.log appears any logging.

I also tried a absolute file-/pathname.

I reduced the Xmx to a size, where a GC definitly would happen after a short time.

Comment: Have you tried calling `System.gc()` manually?

Comment: Yes i did. Unfortunately no result in the gc.log or java console.

Comment: Calling System.gc() does not output any log. It merely cause a full GC.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this comment in the jnlp spec:

> "The JNLP Client may honor this
>   preference only if it considers each
>   argument to be secure."

It's possible that *all* arguments are ignored because *one* of them is unrecognized. What if you specify *only* -verbose:gc and leave out the other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the reference page:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources

it seems like gclog-flag is not supported in Java Web Start, I have not found any way to activate gc-logging in JWS. It probably is a security issue of writing files to the client computer.